# Open specific image from album

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera

I'm making a simple Android app and from my app I want to take an image and save it in the album. After the image is taken I take the 'requestCode' in a database (saveImageId).

```
public void makePicture(){
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_ID);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_ID) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        Log.d("picture receive","foto ok?");
        saveImageId = requestCode;
        _ivPicture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

When I want to show the image I read the code out of the database. I have to search the image with the requestCode and show it to the user.

Anyone got any idea how I can show the image in the _ivPicture?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,
had to save the place of the picture:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_ID) {
        Log.d("picture receive","foto ok?"+requestCode+" & "+resultCode);
        Uri pictureTaken = data.getData();
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        saveImageId = pictureTaken.toString();
        Log.d("saveImageId=",""+saveImageId);
        _ivPicture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

the saveImageId is going to the database (as a string), afterwards I had to load the image again with : `Uri myUri = Uri.parse(saveImageId);
            _ivPicture.setImageURI(myUri);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct the main part of your code above.

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_ID) {
    Uri uri = data.getData(); 
    Bitmap thumbnail = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
    _ivPicture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: the code I wrote works, If I try your code It gives an error on the Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

Comment: then what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I have an input field where I can give a title and set a picture. That works great and it stores the title & the requestCode (don't know if that's good). Now the user wants to change the image on that specific title. So I tab the title and I have to open the textfield with the title and the image that belongs to the title. Editing the title works good, but it doesn't open the image. Question is; how do I open a specific foto. Hope I explained it good.

Comment: I did not understand properly. Besides, I don't see what the problem you are facing has to do with the code you have put up in your question. Also storing the requestCode doesn't seem useful.

Comment: No, just read something and the requestCode isn't useful. I don't have any problem with the code, there has to be more code. I take the picture and it can be previewed in my application. I want to save a link or something that refers to that picture in my database. For example; I take a picture of my pc, the picture has a name, normally a number, so let's say the picture has the name 1234.jpg. 1234 is stored in the database. So when I need to open the picture again (after a while), my program can look in the database and ask 'which picture do I have to show?' The databank returns 1234.

Comment: more specific, I saved the bitmap (android.graphics.Bitmap@435dbca0) To the database as a String. Now I want to open the that specific image in another function. Is there a way for doing this, something like converting that string to a bitmap? I tried 'Object test = savedBitmap; Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) test;' without any succes

Comment: You should write the bitmap object to a file, and save the full path (including file name) to the DB.

Comment: found it, I really appreciate your help Rajath! Thanks